# VBA drag formula from left to right

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to drag a formula from a cell to another cell to the right (i.e. `cellA1 [formula: A2 + A3] -> cellB1 [formula: B2+B3])`. Here is what I have:

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

cellSource = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(3, lastColumn)
cellTarget = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(3, lastColumn + 1)

cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Error is "Object Required"

Comment: you know, instead of using AutoFill, you could just set the formula in the cells using `cells(row, col).formula="=B2+b3"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Dim lastColumn As Long, cellSource As Range, cellTarget As Range
lastColumn = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set cellSource = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Range(Cells(3, lastColumn).Address)
Set cellTarget = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Range(Cells(3, lastColumn), Cells(3, lastColumn + 1))

cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

ranges are objects, so you should use the **set** keyword when assigning values to those variables:

try this:

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

set cellSource = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(3, lastColumn)
set cellTarget = Workbook2.Worksheets(7).Cells(3, lastColumn + 1)

cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: tried to use the **set**. still got an error though. 

"autofill method of range class failed"

highlighted part is this line:

cellSource.AutoFill Destination:=cellTarget, Type:=xlFillDefault